# Do I need to disable active geo-replication on Azure SQL Database prior to update

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, geo-replication

I'm using active geo-replication on a production Azure SQL Database for failover scenario's. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-geo-replication-overview)

Soon we'll be performing an upgrade of our application that uses this database, and some DDL updates are required to the primary database, which leads to a few questions. Answers to any\all would be appreciated!

1. Do I need to disable geo-replication to perform db updates against the primary?
2. If I don't disable geo-replication, would the DDL statements performed against the primary automatically change the secondary db as well?
3. When performing these updates, if we wanted to keep the "secondary" database around for a rollback scenario, I assume we can disable geo-replication to keep that database temporarily "stale".  Is there a means to use that database as a restore point for the primary database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No
2. Yes, this is how it keeps an RPO < 5 seconds as per [this
   link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-business-continuity#sql-database-features-that-you-can-use-to-provide-business-continuity)
3. This is a complex question.  Essentially, you could break the
   geo-replication and then perform the updates.  If you need to switch
   to the secondary, you would simply need to update your connection
   strings and do that.  Bringing the primary back in sync could be as
   simple as enabling geo-replication on the now primary and point it
   back to the old primary.  Eventually you can switch the "primary" back to the old primary using [this cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Azure/?view=azuresmps-3.7.0).  You can also do a [geo-restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-recovery-using-backups#geo-restore).  Ultimately, you can also restore a snapshot of the primary database in the primary region and then fail to that one if something goes wrong.  Re-enable geo-replication as required after that.

Comment: Is #3 also essentially the process when you have failed over to a secondary due to primary outtage, and then when the primary comes back up you need to bring it back in sync?

Comment: That should happen automatically